# error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy usando Angular 8.3 y TypeScript 3.5.3 después de instalar Nebular versión 5.1.0 al trata de compilar me lanza este error **error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context**

[image: Error]

Comment: Faltaría ver el código que produce ese error

Comment: Es posible que sea un bug de Typescript, estoy leyendo en varios sitios que actualizando la versión de TS se soluciona el error